# how to get the next/previous cell definition when onclick of tab key in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I am using `ag-grid` and I need to show the next cell definition and previous cell definition using tab event in `ag-grid`. Please find the [**plnkr url**](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/XI5RyoREJ5TSLt7l?preview).
Please provide your inputs to get the next/previous cell definition when on click of tab key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer documentation: [Example Custom Navigation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#example-custom-navigation)

There is an event and attribute for this.

```
[tabToNextCell]="tabToNextCell"
[navigateToNextCell]="navigateToNextCell"
```

Also refer [tabToNextCell](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#tabtonextcell).

```
interface TabToNextCellParams {

  // true if the shift key is also down
  backwards: boolean;

  // true if the current cell is editing (you may want to skip cells that are not editable,
  // as the grid will enter the next cell in editing mode also if tabbing)
  editing: boolean;

  // the cell that currently has focus
  previousCellDef: GridCellDef;

  // the cell the grid would normally pick as the next cell for this navigation
  nextCellDef: GridCellDef;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.